Op type not registered 'Bitcast' in binary running
I trained my own Faster R-CNN model using pre-trained models from the model zoo,and I need to use tensorflow c_api to predict the model, here is the code to load the model.
TF_SessionOptions* session_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
TF_Buffer* run_opts = NULL;
TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();
TF_Buffer* meta_graph = TF_NewBuffer();
const char* saved_model_dir = "/saved_model";
const char* tags[] = {"serve"};
int ntags = 1;
TF_Session* sess = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(session_opts, run_opts, saved_model_dir, tags, ntags, graph, NULL, status);

The error occurred while loading the model is as follows:
F tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/xla_op_registry.cc:230] Non-OK-status: lookup_status status: NOT_FOUND: Op type not registered 'Bitcast' in binary running on lin-VirtualBox. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
Aborted (core dumped)

How can I solved this problem?
Tensorflow version:2.7.0
ubuntu 20.04
I tried to freeze model again, but it still not work.

Hi @Vin, The error message "Op type not registered 'Bitcast' in binary" suggests that the Bitcast operation, which is part of your pre-trained Faster R-CNN model, is not supported or recognized in the TensorFlow binary being used for prediction with the C API. Ensure compatibility between the TensorFlow version used during model training and the version used for prediction. The model might have been trained with a TensorFlow version that includes the Bitcast operation by default. However, TensorFlow 2.7.0 and newer versions might require explicit registration

If your model incorporates custom or less common operations, it's crucial to verify that these operations are registered correctly. In your situation, 'Bitcast' appears to be causing issues. Whether it's a custom operation or part of a specialized TensorFlow extension, ensure that the extension is installed and initialized correctly to support the operation seamlessly. This ensures that TensorFlow recognizes and processes 'Bitcast' or any other custom operations as intended during prediction with the C API.
